# Update a JSON array on change

Tags: lightning-web-components, json, array

I am trying to update a JSON array on change of a value. I am able to find the position where we need to change but when I try to change the element value it shows a sorry interruption popup box.
Does anyone know a solution for how to update a value in the JSON array. Below is the code which I tried to update the JSON:

```
this.stateData.forEach((element, index) => {
   if (element.Id == event.detail.Id) {
       element.Course__c = event.detail.Course__c;
   }
});
this.stateData = [...this.stateData];
```

Answer (score 1):

if `stateData` is a `json` array you wont be able to access properties `Id` and `Course__c` as every element of array is a `json` string. So in each loop iteration, first you have to parse the json string to object, update the object, parse it again to a string, and then update the array element. You can also use map array function for this.